# Is there a Google Bookmarks plugin for Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, bookmarks

I currently use Google Bookmarks via the Google toolbar plug-in for Firefox. I find this extremely useful as it allows me to have roaming bookmarks rather than having to maintain bookmarks on individual machines and also restore them when rebuilding a machine.

Is there currently any way to use Google Bookmarks in Chrome? This is the one thing I'm waiting for that is preventing me from switching from Firefox to Chrome.

Answer (score 6):

You could switch to [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com) (formerly Foxmarks), which has plugins for Firefox, Chrome, IE, Safari, and maybe more.

Comment: Former Google Bookmarks user here. I switched to Xmarks a while ago - much better, much more reliable. Also, I didn't know Xmarks works with Chrome. I think this is just about enough to push me to switch over from Firefox to Chrome. It was bound to happen anyway. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: The Chrome plugin is not a public beta yet.  Joining a private beta program is hardly sage advice.

Answer (score 1):

I think Xmarks is way better by now but there's another alternative if you like: with a dev build (by now) you can sync your bookmarks with a Google account. AFAIK it doesn't work for Linux yet.

You can find the details @ http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/08/sync-google-chrome-bookmarks.html

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://sites.google.com/site/uniformedopinion/) extension is incomplete (one-way sync only).

There is a safe and easy way using a bookmarklet and a search keyword: http://metaed.blogspot.com/2008/12/using-google-bookmarks-in-google-chrome.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course you can use Google bookmarks in Chrome, my favorite Chrome extension for that is [Google bookmark](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/fhaicgmeeafgboeobjagfmlcdhbkijhf?hl=en). Very simple and easy to use, but usefull.