# How can I quickly access my Google Bookmarks?

Tags: google-chrome

Before migrating to Chrome, I used Firefox with the Google Toolbar.  What I liked most about the toolbar was the quick access it gave me to my Google Bookmarks.

Is there an easy way to access the Google Bookmarks from within Chrome, or is the only way using this link?

> [Google Bookmarks](https://www.google.com/bookmarks/l)  (must be logged in to Google)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I Think you have to follow this procedure. It's not straight forward, but it should get your job done.

1) Login to [Google Bookmarks](http://www.google.com/bookmarks)

2) Click Export Bookmarks (or visit http://www.google.com/bookmarks/bookmarks.html)
and download the file to your computer.

3) In Chrome, choose IMPORT BOOKMARKS & SETTINGS.

4) Choose Favorites/Bookmarks and select FireFox.

Now, all of your Google Bookmarks should appear under the Other
bookmarks folder in the bookmarks for Chrome.

Some of the credits should go [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fftoolbar-suggestions/L1c_ldvdVaw).

Comment: Ok - Understood.  But then all my bookmarks are on the local computer/in Chrome.  The nice thing with the Tool Bar is the bookmarks were "in the cloud".    Seems Chrome is not embracing "cloud computing" as well as it can.

Comment: In Chrome, you can sync your bookmarks/settings/extensions with your Google account. See http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=165139&from=165140&rd=1

Comment: Thanks.  I would have thought it be better integrated with your online google account; it still caches these locally.  And they advise: Be careful if you share your browser with multiple people. If someone signs in to the sync feature with his or her Google Account on your computer, your settings on that computer will be added to the Google Account.

Comment: It is a problem if the computer is shared. You may have to look for other alternatives like Delicious Bookmarks, or XMarks. There are nice extensions available for this. Here's my own [Delicious extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lnapbapmncaacbfijemonkinanfaebhm). It's pretty light-weight, so may not be of interest for you!

Comment: Google Bookmarks are not available any more. You should remove this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This extension to your Google Chrome will work for you:

[YAGBE - Yet Another Google Bookmarks™ Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jdnejaepfmacfdmhkplckpfdcjgbeode)

Your Google Bookmarks are synced into this extension. It provides an Extension button and an Extension-style popup. The search is not integrated with the Address Bar.

It is pretty fast at searching through my 5000+ entries for the titles and labels. (Google Chrome 15 stable on Windows)

You may also want to review this old answer for [Is there a Google Bookmarks plugin for Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/54342/is-there-a-google-bookmarks-plugin-for-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Best way for **fast access to Google Bookmarks with Chrome**  :

*Online Bookmark IncSearch*

so far as I found. Display quite clear. Superior to other such as YAGBE in
that once called it stays open until you close it.

Still a bit slower than access still available thru a Google gadget within
igoogle, but that is understandable as the gadget is provided by Googl*e*.
Anyway Google is about past.

I forget wherefrom I dowloaded this extension but it is easy to find about
and installation was for me immediate and painless.

Functionalities means the usual, find a bookmark, and display found bookmarks.
characters found are highlighted (or is it highlit ?). Very small but clear Help..
Not present in other products I tried: full display of the comments you entered
in a bookmark. Edit is available.